# Encrypt text using .NET libraries that matches encryption from aspEncrypt

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

We have an legacy web application which is using Persits Software's aspEncrypt. I have thousands of files encrypted with that setup so I need to stay compatible.

I am trying to write a new utility application in C# to match that same encryption. The goal here is to NOT use aspEncrypt in the new application and to match the encryption using the stuff built into the .NET framework. If successful then I could use the same legacy decryption routines on both the legacy and new files.

Sample code for how I handle the encryption step using aspEncrypt:

```
public static int EncryptFileWithRawKey2()
{
    string InputFile = @"D:\TEMP\004\testfile.txt"; // contains single line of ANSI text with no end of line characters "hello this is a file"
    string OutPutFile = @"D:\TEMP\004\testfile.txt.3.xxx";
    string RawKey = "4CDD1518CD6662C9D1583A8732173EDC";

    int iRet = 0;

    ASPENCRYPTLib.ICryptoKey eKey = null;

    try
    {
        ASPENCRYPTLib.CryptoManager CM = new ASPENCRYPTLib.CryptoManager();
        ASPENCRYPTLib.ICryptoContext Context = CM.OpenContext("", 0, 0);

        ASPENCRYPTLib.ICryptoBlob Blob = CM.CreateBlob();
        Blob.Hex = RawKey;
        eKey = Context.ImportRawKey(Blob, ASPENCRYPTLib.CryptoAlgorithms.calgRC2);

        ASPENCRYPTLib.ICryptoBlob IVblob = CM.CreateBlob();
        IVblob.Hex = "0000000000000000";
        eKey.SetIV(IVblob);


        eKey.Mode = ASPENCRYPTLib.CryptoCipherModes.ccmCBC;
        eKey.Padding = ASPENCRYPTLib.CryptoCipherPadding.ccpPKCS5;
        eKey.EffectiveLength = 40;

        eKey.EncryptFile(InputFile.Trim(), OutPutFile.Trim());
        if (File.Exists(OutPutFile) == true)
            iRet = 1;


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EncryptFileWithRawKey2 FAILED");
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        iRet = - 1;
    }

    return iRet;
}
```

And here is the code I wrote in what has so far been an unsuccessful attempt to match it:

```
public static void EncryptTextToFile2()
{

    String Data = "hello this is a file";
    String FileName = @"D:\TEMP\004\testfile.txt.4.xxx";
    String sTempKey = "4CDD1518CD6662C9D1583A8732173EDC";

    byte[] Key;
    byte[] IV;

    try
    {
        Key = StringToByteArray(sTempKey);
        IV = StringToByteArray("0000000000000000");

        FileStream fStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        RC2 RC2alg = RC2.Create();
        RC2alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        RC2alg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        RC2alg.KeySize = 40;
        RC2alg.EffectiveKeySize = 40;

        CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, RC2alg.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(cStream);
        sWriter.WriteLine(Data);

        sWriter.Close();
        cStream.Close();
        fStream.Close();

    }
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A file error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
    }

}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

The output from the two routines does not match. I cannot change the logic which uses the AspEncrypt libraries so I need to change the second section of code in some way to match the output from the first.

Comment: the question that pops into my head is why are you trying to do this? What is the end goal? Get rid of this aspEncrypt library?

Comment: The end goal is to allow two independent systems to pass encrypted files back & forth. Since we already have thousands of encrypted files in use we don't want to change the method. The one web based system will continue to use AspEncrypt and ideally the second system will implement the same method using the System.Security.Cryptography stuff built into .NET.